# Setting a fixed date and counting the number of days to an input birthdate to determing day of week - Java

Tags: java, date

My task is such - I need to set a specific date - 01/01/1913, which is a wednesday. I then need the user to input their birthdate. The program will then calculate which day of the week the person was born in. We are not allowed to use the gregorian calendar to do it for us, we are required to input the algorithm ourselves.

So far, I have the input set up,

```
public class FindDay4Birthdate 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // declare variables
        String bbday = "";
        String bbmonth = "";
        String bbyear = "";
        int bday;
        int bmonth;
        int byear;

        String daysList[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your date of birth - ");
        sc.useDelimiter("[-/.\\s]");
        if (sc.hasNext()); {
            bbday = sc.next();
            bbmonth = sc.next();
            bbyear=sc.next();
            bday = Integer.parseInt(bbday);
            bmonth = Integer.parseInt(bbmonth);
            byear = Integer.parseInt(bbyear);
        } // end if statement
    }
}
```

I am not sure where to go from here. Any help on how to take the next step would be appreciated. I know that I need to use mod 7, but do not know how, or where, I should use it.

Comment: *"We are not allowed to use the gregorian calendar to do it for us"* - Why not? Do you mean to just parse their birthdate to get the Day or not allowed to use it at all? Are you allowed to use `util.Calendar` at least?

Comment: you have to count the days%7

Comment: Also note you have a `;` after your if statement so it actually will always execute what is inbetween the `{ }`

Comment: The task states we must use an algorithm to compute the number of days, taking into consideration leap years. We need to include an algorithm to calculate the leap years. Unfortunately the GCal does that for me, so I would receive marks for correct output, but not for correct implementation.


nachokk, thanks for that. I'll see what I can put together.

Java Devil, where exactly do you mean? I tried to remove several different ;'s, but recieved build errors. Probably due to my poor skills ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Count the days between  from 01/01/1913 to user input, count also +1 day for leap-years

2) The result of 1) %7 , will give you the remainder, if is 0 then it's Wednesday, if not you have to count 1= Thursday 2=Friday .etc...

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular algorithm you are supposed to implement?  If so, could you update your question with it so we can help you with the Java implementation?

If you are struggling with the algorithm itself, take a look at Wikipedia's [Determination of the day of the week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week) for a quite thorough explanation of various ways to calculate the day of week.

The formula given in the section titled [Basic method for mental calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Basic_method_for_mental_calculation) the formula is (d + m + y + floor(y\4) + c) mod 7 where

> - d is the day of the month,
> - m is the month's number in the [months table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Months_table),
> - y is the last two digits of the year
> - c is the century number. For a Gregorian date, this is 6 if the first two digits of the year are evenly divisible by 4, and subsequent
>     centuries are 4-2-0 (so the century numbers for 2000, 2100, 2200, and
>     2300 are respectively 6, 4, 2, and 0). For a Julian date, this is 6
>     for 1200, and subsequent centuries subtract 1 until 0, when the next
>     century is 6 (so 1300 is 5, and 1100 is 0).
>
> If the result is 0, the date was a Sunday; if 1 it was a Monday, and
>   so on...

Comment: i didn't know that formula , nice to know, but with that, his precondition has no sense..

Comment: @nachokk January 1st 1913 _was_ a Wednesday which the referenced algorithm will calculate.  Maybe I misunderstood the question but the way I read it, that's simply provided as a reference point.

Comment: Yes but , if he has that date he want do something with that day! is like relevant data to solve the problem, with the magic formula is not needed, that i was trying to say

Comment: After (re)reading OP's question several times, I think I understand what @nachokk is saying.  Although the solution I've given is a general algorithm for calculating day of week, it does not use the 1/1/1913 seed date as the basis for this calculation.

Comment: That formula is very helpful, and the way you have put it is nice and easy to understand. Unfortunately I am required to use 1/1/1913 as a base date. Makes it unnecessarily complex!

Answer (score 1):

what you may be looking for is [Zeller's Congruence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence)

Comment: This! This worked perfectly! Thank you very much, I think I can go on from here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use the [Calendar class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) (but probably not), do the following

```
Calendar birthday = Calendar.getInstance();
birthday.set(byear,bmonth - 1,bday);

//Create your time 1/1/1913
Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
startDate.set(1913,0,1);

int numberOfDays = 0;

//Loop counting days
while(startDate.before(birthday))
{
    numberOfdays++;
    startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

//Get index for your days array
int index = ((numberOfDays%7)+3)%7;
String day = daysList[index];
```